# How can I add data to PostgreSQL in real-time chatbot based on Django websockets?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create real-time chat using Django back-end and Angular 4 front-end with **PostgreSQL** database. Let's assume that I would like to create chat robot for instance like [A.L.I.C.E](http://alice.pandorabots.com). It seems to me that the most optimal solution would be to use websockets? I create channel layer using **Redis**. Now, I would like to save all messages to my **PostgreSQL** database. I wonder how it should be done. Should I create models and use them in `consumers.py` or maybe there is an another more optimal way? In the future I would like to analyze data from database and return the answer.

consumers.py:

```
# In consumers.py
from channels import Group

# Connected to websocket.connect
def ws_connect(message):
    # Accept the connection
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    # Add to the chat group
    Group("chat").add(message.reply_channel)

# Connected to websocket.receive
def ws_receive(message):
    Group("chat").send({
        "text": message.content['text'],
    })
    print(message.content['text'])

# Connected to websocket.disconnect
def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group("chat").discard(message.reply_channel)
```

routing.py:

```
from channels.routing import route
from backend.consumers import ws_connect, ws_receive, ws_disconnect

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
]
```

settings.py:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        # This example app uses the Redis channel layer implementation asgi_redis
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [(redis_host, 6379)],
        },
        "ROUTING": "backend.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, so create a model in your `models.py` for example `Message` model.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
```

and import it to `consumers.py`

```
#consumers.py
from .models import Message

def ws_receive(message):
Group("chat").send({
    "text": message.content['text'],
})
msg = Message()
msg.message = message.content['text']
msg.save()
```

But if you will use this snippet in production, it **will** hit your database performance. But as I heard, you can make some kind of queue with python module [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing) and save messages from that queue. I haven't seen implementation with custom queues, so you should make your own.